# Explanation about a code generation in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, code-generation

I want to know :

1. The purpose of `code generation` in Magento 2 ?
2. How it works, (how Magento generate that code) ?

**I know basic code generation**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Magento2** generates code to create non-existent classes, for exemple a `Factory Object` in CRUD Models.

The `Factory` class name is the name of Model class and append with the `Factory` word. for exemple your model is : `app/code/Vendor/module/Model/Boot.php`, the Factory object class will be: `app/code/Vendor/module/Model/BootFactory.php` without create this `BootFactory.php`, Magento create it for us automatically in `var/generation` folder.

```
var/generation/Vendor/module/Model/BootFactory.php
```

**Advantages of generating code :**

Code generation is required in **Magento 2**. Generating code **assures** you of the following:

- The code is correct. You don’t have to worry that the generated code is delegating to the wrong method or forgetting a semicolon, and you don’t have to write tests for the generated code.
- Code generation writes the boilerplate code to enable you to write more challenging and interesting code.
- Consistent implementation.
- All generated Factories **work the same way**. After you know how one Factory works, you know how they all work.

More information in Magento [DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html).